# Definition of Stable, Unstable and Neutral Equilibrium using Force

Tags: forces, potential-energy, equilibrium

So I have read that a particle is in Stable Equilibrium when the potential energy is minimum, Unstable Equilibrium when the potential energy is maximum and Neutral Equilibrium when the potential energy is neither maximum or minimum. All of these definitions have the condition that net force on the particle = $0$ (or the particle is at equilibrium or $\frac {dU}{dr} = 0$.

Some extensions of these concepts or different definitions of Equilibrium are : "A particle is said to be in Stable Equilibrium when a slight displacement of the particle from equilibrium position makes it oscillate about that position (which means it returns back to the mean position) or that the forces acting on the particle are in the opposite direction to the displacement. The particle is in Unstable Equilibrium when a slight displacement of the particle from equilibrium position makes it go farther away from the position (which means it cannot come back to the mean position) or the forces acting on the particle are in the direction of displacement."

My doubt is : what is the condition of force for neutral equilibrium (like for Stable Equilibrium - force opposite to displacement and for Unstable Equilibrium - force along direction of displacement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of stable equilibrium is a ball in a bowl. If the ball is displaced sideways, it is higher than the equilibrium position. It loses potential energy if it rolls back to equilibrium. Not coincidentally, the force on a displaced ball is toward the equilibrium position. You can think about how force is related to the derivative of potential energy to see why.

A ball on a plane is an example of neutral equilibrium. No change in potential energy on displacement. No force.

A ball on a hill is in unstable equilibrium.

A ball at the inflection point of curve $y=x^3$ illustrates why $\frac{dU}{dr}$ isn't a bulletproof definition of neutral equilibrium. If displaced toward positive x, the force pushes it toward the "equilibrium" position. If displaced toward negative x, the force pushes it away. This is not a neutral equilibrium.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HwyG.png) the point A is stable equilibrium, B is unstable equilibrium and C is neutral equilibrium rather than demonstrated [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1BWF.png)?
Basically, for neutral equilibrium, it is necessary for the force to be = $0$ around that point in atleast 1 direction (like positive x or negative x or both)?

Comment: In the first image, C looks a little stable. For neutral, it would be a table top. Neutral stability requires the force to be 0 in all directions. It is more a vocabulary question than a physics question what to call it if it is attractive in one directions and neutral in others. A skater in a half pipe is attracted to the line at the bottom. If it is unstable in one direction, it is unstable. A small random deviation gets pushed away from equilibrium.

Comment: Ok so C is like stable equilibrium because if you push it in one 
direction it tends to return back to that position, but after it crosses C again it just keeps going away and away. How is that stable Equilibrium? Also, is D in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB647.png) a point of neutral Equilibrium now?

Comment: I misunderstood your diagram. D is neutral. C is neither stable nor neutral.

Comment: oh ok, now i understand the concept clearly. Thank you for your patience to make me understand

Comment: I have just one doubt left and it's above the character limit for comments, so I have posted a [new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786523/identification-of-stable-unstable-neutral-equilibrium) 
kindly check the question

Answer (score 1):

These definitions are only good for simple physical systems and start to break down when we push them to their limits. For example, if I take your first definition of Neutral equilibrium, it includes an extremum point where the second derivative $\frac{d^2U}{dr^2}$ changes sign. I find it hard to call that neutral.

If we take your oscillatory definition of Stable equilibrium then one can again cook up a system where it would oscillate, but with increasing amplitude. And it gets much worse if we consider more than one dimension. A good general definition of equilibrium can be found on wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability

Coming back to your question, the only way I can think of Neutral equilibrium is if there is a region of zero force around the equilibrium point.

Comment: So if we displace the particle through a little bit, then it just stays there (because you said  there is a region of zero force around it)? But if we take an example with a pe graph as [the graph given in the 1st answer of this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646155/clarification-in-the-definition-of-stable-and-unstable-equilibrium?rq=1). It shows that one side is a minima and one side a maxima so if in this case it is displaced slightly then it is not necessary that it stays at the new position but rather starts moving, doesn't it?

Comment: That answer has an issue with it. It's not clear if the region just around the equilibrium they called neutral is flat or not. I.e. if it's similar to the $y=x^3$ curve as pointed out by the answer above. If the force is not zero in some small region, then there will be movement with any displacement and the equilibrium wouldn't be neutral.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. Thank you for explaining the concept