# Identification of Stable, Unstable, Neutral Equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

Definition of Stable Equilibrium - When a particle is displaced infinitesimally, it returns back to the mean position and starts oscillating about it. Unstable Equilibrium - When a particle is displaced infinitesimally, it runs off to a point far away (or infinity). Neutral Equilibrium - When a particle is displaced infinitesimally, it neither returns to the mean position nor does it run off to a very far point (or infinity) but stabilises somewhere.
All of these definitions are obviously valid for a point of equilibrium (net force = 0 or $\frac {dU}{dr}$) and for any equilibrium point has to be defined. (I also have a problem in the contradicting basic definitions of the Equilibrium types and force definitions of these equilibriums. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786519/contradicting-basic-and-force-definitions-of-types-of-equilibrium))

Let us say we have such a graph :

[image]

Here according to mathematical definitions of unstable equilibrium ($\frac {dU}{dr} = 0$ & $\frac {d^2U}{dr^2} < 0$) we can get that point F is unstable equilibrium, but using the (first) basic definition of unstable equilibrium, we can see that displacing the particle infinitesimally from F does not make it run off to a very far point and rather stabilises at E or G. Will this be termed neutral equilibrium? (what if the height of F would be just more than that of H and height of H would be same as that of D, then after slight displacement from F, the particle would come to rest at H or D. In this case would we say F is neutral equilibrium?

Let us consider point C which according to the mathematical definitions of unstable equilibrium ($\frac {dU}{dr} = 0$ & $\frac {d^2U}{dr^2} = 0$) is a point of neutral equilibrium but when you displace a particle infinitesimally from it towards the left (or right, it will first move up a bit and then the same thing happens as when displaced to the left), it starts moving down and has enough Kinetic Energy to cross A to finally run off to a far away point (or infinity). Will this be termed Unstable Equilibrium?

Let us consider point I where the slope of the curve goes from negative to $0$. A slight displacement to the right will do nothing and the particle will just stay there but a slight displacement to the left will cause it to gain Kinetic Energy/velocity and it will keep going till infinity. Will this be termed Unstable Equilibrium?

Just to confirm my understanding of the other points - A, D, H are points of Unstable Equilibrium, B, E, G are points of Stable Equilibrium, J is Neutral Equilibrium

Comment: You seem to have a good understanding of the behavior. That is more important that names.

Comment: I understand that mostly behaviour of particles is only important but what I am asking is what if we needed to attach a specific type to these equilibriums mentioned above. What would we call them?

Answer (score 0):

If every small displacement results in an attractive force toward the equilibrium position, this is stable equilibrium. If every small displacement results in no force, this is neutral. If any small displacement results in a repulsive force, this is unstable. Anything else doesn't have a name

Comment: By repulsive force, do you mean exactly along the displacement or do you mean any force that causes the particle to run off from the equilibrium position?